# Did God forgive Adam and Eve?

Tags: forgiveness, adam-and-eve, prophet-adam

I learned from the Quran that our first parents, Adam and Eve, were living in Paradise until they committed sin/wrong. Quran says that they were forgiven of their sins/wrongdoing. If they were forgiven of their sin/wrong, then why did God being so merciful and gracious make them leave the garden? Does it mean He did not forgive them?"

Comment: There can be no forgiveness, if there is punishment. And if there is punishment, there can be no forgiviness.

Comment: Isn't the story of Adam and Eve from the Torah/Bible? This should be moved to `judaism.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @Curious1 Adam and Eve were found before judaism ever existed! Their story is not limited to Torah/Bible only.

Comment: @Jawad Your claim sounds very weird to me, can you support it with a quran/hadeeth reference? In fact, all worldly punishments (حدود) are basically to guarantee forgiveness. If someone steals, and wants to repentant he may do it silently and God will/may accept him. The stealer may, also, go to the judge and confess, At this case his hands should be cut (punishment) and the stealer will be forgiven.

Answer (score 8):

There were four sequential steps in Adam's story:

- Order/Command

> [ [2:35](http://tanzil.net/#2:35) ] And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat therefrom in [ease and] abundance from wherever you will. But do not approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers."

- Sin

> [ [2:36](http://tanzil.net/#2:36) ] But Satan caused them to slip out of it ...

Qortoby Tafseer states that this slip is considered a sin (Arabic reference: [here](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=354&idto=370&bk_no=48&ID=70)). That sin caused them to be punished.

- Punish

> [2:36] and removed them from that [condition] in which they had been. And We said, "Go down, [all of you], as enemies to one another, and you will have upon the earth a place of settlement and provision for a time."

- Repentance, Acceptance and Mercy

> [ [2:37](http://tanzil.net/#2:37) ] Then Adam received from his Lord [some] words, and He accepted his repentance. Indeed, it is He who is the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful.

Comment: Yes but that does not answer the question at all!

Comment: But they remained out of Garden even then.

Comment: Sure it answers! Punishment came first, followed by repentance and forgiveness.

Answer (score 3):

Before **God** blew his breath into Adam (a.s) he told the angels 'this creation of mine shall be my emissary khalifa on earth and I shall place generation after generation of them on earth'. So no, Adam (a.s) was not sent to earth as a punishment, rather it was meant for him to be there before he was even given life.

If you have any other queries just post them and I will try to give you an answer to the best of my knowledge. The answer I have given you is from Quran.

Comment: Can you give a reference to " Before God blew his breath....earth' "?

Answer (score 1):

Adam was forgiven as in The Quran 2:37 and 20:122
Then Adam received from his Lord [some] words, and He accepted his repentance. Indeed, it is He who is the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful. Probably you may ask that if God accepted his repentance ,why didn't God get him back in the Paradise ?
Answer :. According to Al Quran 2: 30
And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know."
He was sent as" Khalifa" or successor on the earth therefore he was to remain on the earth till his death . Hope that's the answer !
And Allah Knows Best !!

Answer (score 0):

Since they come to earth, we have chance to show our good deeds. Since heaven is not the place of *examination* whether a person is good or bad, we, human beings, didn't have chance to show our work. Therefore, by making `Adam and Eve(radiallahu anhum)` leave heaven, **Allah** didn't become unmerciful, in a way, he become merciful to his believer creatures. Even we can say **Allah** was merciful to `Adam and Eve` in that event. `Prophet Adam and Eve` did their best in the life and he is named as **Safiyyullah**(one of the cleanest creature of **Allah**)

Answer (score 0):

My explanation is that It was God's master plan 
To send both Adam and Eve to earth. God
Put them in a test by telling them not to eat
a certain fruit and God knew that Adam and
Eve will not follow his order. As he was merciful
He forgave them when they repented but
ordered them to leave paradise as by eating
the forbidden fruit they had developed sexual
Feeling and were deemed unsuitable for dwelling
in paradise. So He ordered them to go to earth
so that they can reproduce and perform more good deeds. Offcourse satan would stand in
Their ways to do that but it was a test which God
Believed out of His love for human beings that
They must eventually overcome. That is why
God said when Adam and Eve were sent to
Earth that His mercy shall prevail over all wrath.
Dr Haider Mannan

deeds

Answer (score 0):

Yes right, Allah has scenario for Adam to leave Eden. To make him His khalifah.
Other creations can not do that, only Men can do.

Then here we are. big drama of human kind.

Adam is now in jannah, repentance was accepted.

Comment: Thanks for answer! but the answer lacks references from Quran and ahdeeth.

Answer (score 0):

Allah's plan was to let Adam and eve live in earth in the first place, the sin was just to show that the satan is our enemy:

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make **upon the earth** a successive authority." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know." [[2:30]](http://quran.com/2/30)